# How to set the Height of the Iframe Dynamically as per the content loading in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

This question has been posted a lot of times, i have referred them but not working for me. I have an iframe which loads another wesite in it. I want that the height of the iframe must be change dynamically as per the height of the website page loading in it. No manual height settings. How can i do that?

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/" width:150;></iframe>
```

Could anyone please fiddle and show me? Advance thanks for help. Fiddle link below:

[link] ( http://jsfiddle.net/vineetgnair/5p0pL5zu/ )

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to do in a cross-browser safe way as it may seem. You are better off using a JavaScript library that does it for you. I have used [this one](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) with success before.

Comment: +1, just to you give you a start, [this works in Chrome and Firefox](http://jsfiddle.net/9o68z8uq/), but as @Smyrnian mentions, it gets kind of complicated when dealing with cross-browser and [cross-domain issues (same-origin policy)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy]), it's probably best to stick with an existing library instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

you have an error in code that is

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/" width=150;></iframe>
```

that is colon(:) has to replace equal(=)

if you want responsiveness make the width in percentage it gives you full responsive

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/" width=100%;></iframe>
```

Comment: thanks "it's me", but as of now its not the width but the height that concerns me. I really don't mind setting the width manually through CSS but the height needs to be dynamic means the iframe must re-size its height as per the height of the website in it..

Comment: Okay, I think my answer is correct of your previous question, Am I right!

Comment: make the height as 100% you got full length of your web due to your screen size

Answer (score 0):

first you need to full height your `iframe` using some css technique given in the below css section. then take the height of that iframe(full height of given url in the `src` iframe), pass that height to iframe..

the css:

```
  <style>
body,
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    /*set your width here*/
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
}
  </style>
```

the body section:

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" frameborder="0" width="100%"  id="frameid">   </iframe>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var theHeight = $('#frameid').height();
$('#frameid').attr('height', theHeight);
console.log(theHeight);
</script>
```